# How to update data to mysql although some textboxes are blank? (The data of blank textboxes will be kept)

Tags: c#, mysql

I want to update the data through textboxes and if some of the textboxes are blank, then the data, which supposed to be updated by those textboxes, would be kept.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a user facing application and the text boxes have existing data associated, a much better UI would involve actually loading that data out and displaying it to the user so they know all the information that will be contained in the record.

Then you can not update fields that match if that is important for some reason.

If for some reason this is impossible, individual update statements guarded by if is not blank checks could get the job done, or case statements in a single update statement involving the database value if the update value is blank, but this all seems like a hack to me.